# Ping failed when linking SQL server with java in eclipse

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse

I'm trying to link SQL server with java SE 8.0 in eclipse. But every time I got a Ping error message.

I studied the documentations about how to connect them and also the errors, but non of them helps.

By selecting SQL 2008, the URL address is  `'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=pubs'`, and the result of test connection is:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'Nastaran'. ClientConnectionId:aceb876b-7c92-454c-bab0-9c176045bb76
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2964)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2244)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2230)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1717)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1328)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:993)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:829)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.msft.internal.sqlserver.connection.JDBCSQLServerConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCSQLServerConnectionFactory.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Can anyone help me?
```

Comment: Do you have access to the DB host you are trying to connect? Are you using the correct host name? Can you `ping` that host from command lime?

Comment: My hostname is DESKTOP-1T3IHMM. I can ping it from command line.

Answer (score 1):

- 1.Open your SQL Server Management Studio
- Connect to Window Authentication
- right click on the **sqlexpress** in the *object_explorer*==>**Properties**==>**Security**
- Select **SQL server and window Authentication**
- IF you do not have user and you use window authentication , create a
  new user

---

***CREATING NEW USER***

- Click **Security**  in the *object explorer* ==> **LOGIN**
- Enter login name  **"Student001"** choose **SQL server and window
  Authentication**
- then click **Server Role** under *GENERAL* and check the checkbox u need to check
  then click ok.
- restart the SQL server.

---

- url format :
  jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-CQEEAQ3\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=Customer;
  DESKTOP-CQEEAQ3\SQLEXPRESS : copied from SSMS Server Name.